# Putting null value into HashMap is not possible somehow

Tags: java, android, null, hashmap

I'm writing an Android application and use `HashMap<String,MyClass>`. According to Java and Android documentation the HashMap should accept both null keys and values. But, strangely, I can't put null value into my map. In the code:

```
myMap.put(1, null);
```

I'm getting the error:

`The method put(String, MyClass) in the type HashMap<String,MyClass> is not applicable for the arguments (int, null)`.

Why is that? What can be wrong and how to fix?

Comment: You just need to look at the basics of language first and then come here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value is not the issue in this case. Since the HashMap is declared to have a String key and you're trying to put an int key in, it's not complaining about the value but the key.

Comment: You are genious! I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes ;-) The site don't allow this right now.

Answer (score 7):

Because you are using a key of type int and it was declared to except a key of type String.

Answer (score 2):

HashMap is declared to have a String key and you're trying to put an int key.

In your case you can use the following:

```
myMap.put("1", null);
```

or

```
myMap.put(1 + "", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

first try to figure out the error then look for the desired solution.Because most of our problem will be solved by looking the error description. It is telling clearly that you have used int instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Integer as a key of your Map then change your Map definition to:

```
Map<Integer,MyClass> myMap = new HashMap();
myMap.put(1, null);
```

Other wise use String as key of your Map:

```
Map<String,MyClass> myMap = new HashMap();
myMap.put("1", null);
```